# Google FIT API response and UI Values didn't match

Tags: google-fit

I'm trying to fetch `steps` metric from Google FIT API, for the requested period of time its not match to the value I'm seeing in my Google FIT account.

e.g. I'm getting 6K steps by API for April 1, but UI shows me something like 8K.

Any ideas? Why is this happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Android API or REST API? Which method are you using?

Comment: @GraemeMorgan REST API

Answer (score 0):

Google Fit detects when users are doing activities that shouldn't contribute to their step count (like cycling, driving or travelling via public transport) and removes these from the final step count.

The Google Fit app shows this more accurate, estimated step count on both the Android and iOS app, and the Google Fit app on smart watches with Wear OS.

If you read by your app's data source rather than by data type, and your app only uses local step data, the step count will be different from the step count in the Google Fit app.

If you're reading the data types but values are still different from the Google Fit app, this temporary difference in numbers could be due to syncing delays. Our backend has the most recent version of data and your app will show the same values once it's synced with the backend.